# Raw pointer over shared pointer when not concerned with memory leak

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, smart-pointers

I would just like someone to confirm or deny my train of thought. Basically I want a vector of pointers that will be created only when the program boots up, and will be needed throughout the life of the program. I don't see a reason to use shared pointers as this will add a small amount of overhead, and since I won't need the memory deallocated until the program closes, I'll be gaining nothing from using a smart pointer to begin with.

Am I right in believing this? I genuinely can't think of a reason a smart pointer would be any more beneficial to me in this instance.

Comment: Why would they have been shared? Do they have multiple owners?

Comment: If you are concerned about overhead, why use pointers instead of direct values?

Comment: _"I'll be gaining nothing from using a smart pointer to begin with"_ - You'll loose nothing by making them `unique_ptr`s and gain a lot later when debugging the program using valgrind and other memory leak detecting tools. Less noise = easier debugging.

Comment: you should use `std::array<T, num>`

Comment: What are the pointers pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case for using a static variable and, yes, raw pointers. I obviously assume that the ownership of the pointers are always clear.

Comment: This is the case for not using pointers at all.

Comment: That is not clear from the post. I assume the OP has a good reason to use pointers and the question is if to use raw or shared pointers.